# Regex Custom Search query for date ranges

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC.net web application with search page. I would like the user to be able to search records by a given year e.g. 1979. However i know some power users will want to search date ranges etc. Rather than redesign the search form i was thinking i could add some extra features by allowing the users to type in:

- **1979** just records for 1979
- **1979+** all years from 1979 forwards
- **1979-** all years from 1979 backwards
- **1979-1985** all years between 1979 and 1980

I can handle the search criteria but i was wondering whats the best way to work out from the string they have entered what action they want to do? Note they can also leave the search string blank as there are other critera on the page.

I was thinking some regex tests but what would the correct regex patterns be? I've tried to create some but i cant get it right.

```
if (Query == Regex for single year)
{
     SQL = SELECT WHERE Year = Query
}
else if (Query = regex for greater than year) {
     SQL = SELECT WHERE Year >= Query
}
else if (Query = regex for less than year) {
    SQL = SELECT WHERE Year <= Query
}
else if (query = regex for date range) {
    SQL = SELECT WHERE Year >= Query Part A AND Year <= Query Part B
}
else { ignore }
```

Comment: You should be using regex for this.  Convert to DateTime and then use between in sql or greater than and less than.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
([1-9][0-9]{3})([+-]?)([1-9][0-9]{3})?
```